# Mesh overlapping moving 3D characters

Tags: c++, 3d, blender, mesh, ogre

I'm making a project where I use a sensor to move a 3d human model, and so far no problem.
But I have some problems of overlap of the mesh, how can I do to prevent the arm from entering the body?
If anyone has any suggestions I would appreciate them.

Is the right way to control bone's orientation?

Comment: You can do collision checks for the arm against the body to eliminate the overlap, or you can set bounds on the maximal movement and constrain the arm movement that way.  I would recommend going with constraints as they will likely be cheaper to check against than a full collision detection routine.  Just thought too: you could have key frames for certain movement types and interpolate until the key-frame state is met: that would be your maximal position for that movement (this is the way MD5 models do it for example): so press left interpolate arm until left move key-frame:)

Comment: unfortunately, Blender does not export constraints for Ogre..

Comment: Hi @velthune  think this post may be of use to you http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=73261  which seems to point to [Smartbody](http://smartbody.ict.usc.edu/) as a method for applying constraints etc to bodies in ogre.

Comment: Thank's a lot for the link, I think I will test soon! (:

Comment: let me know how you get on, I can try and help more over the week/weekend if you need more info:)